# Flask can a route inherit code from another route?

Tags: python, flask

Is it possible for a flask app route to inherit code from another flask app route?

Example

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
    # some code

@app.route('/something')
def something():
    # inherit code from home function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably write a handler that is called by both functions like this:

```py
@app.route('/')
def home():
    shared_code()

@app.route('something')
def something():
    shared_code()

    # other specific code

def shared_code():
    print("this is called by both routes")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without the extra function because I am trying to have only route functions in my views file

Comment: I don't think that there is a way to do this *in python*. You can not inherit functions (just like in other languages) only classes